# The best way to organize search service, which can find data in a big database according to the set of filters

Tags: .net, algorithm, search, tree, olap

We have big dataset (about 191 million of records, will be grow), every record contains the values of filters (11 filters - datetime and integer values), and some additional data (cost). For example:

```
Depature City = 1
Arrival City = 5
Country Id = 7
Check In Date = 2013-05-05
    ... etc

Cost 1250
    ... etc
```

We have a search interface with 11 filters. In every filter user can choose: one value, a set of values, all values.

Every filter have the different set of possible values, it can vary from 4 to 5000 values.

The result of search must be sorted by ascending cost, there are paging (50 result per page)

Every search query must be completed in 100 mS, usually expected 50-70 requests/sec (200 as maximum).

The data will be changes often, but the speed of data changing has the lower priority, than search this process can be slow.

What is the best way to organise such search engine? Data in memory (we tried some tree algoritms), Map-Reduce (Hadoop?), OLAP?

**UPDATE**. What do you think about some in memory solution? The records can be loaded to the operation memory in some good for search and sort structure. What structure is the best?

In production environment, the client will be able to supply appropriate hardware for good solution.

In general, we have a .NET solution - so, this module must be compatible with it.

Comment: Can you clarify.. How fast is 'really fast', how many is 'great amount of requests'?  Eg 90% of queries should complete in N mS, expecting M requests/sec. Also, what is the minimum number of filters a typical query would provide, and how often does the data change.

Comment: When I think of fast NoSQL solutions, Hadoop is not at the top of the list. =) I don't think their map/reduce is going to be "really" fast.

Comment: We have clarified our requirements. Every query must be completed in 100 mS, usually expected 50-70 requests/sec (200 as maximum). There are 11 filters. In every filter user can select: one value, a set of values or all values. The data will be changes often, but the speed of data changing has the lower priority, this process can be slow.

Comment: When you say your data are going to change, do you mean new rows are added or existing rows are updated ?

Comment: There are two process:
1. Recalculation. It leads to creation a new rows and deleting of the obsolete rows. It can make big changes (about 50-70% of the dataset; it makes every half the year during the weekend) or small changes (add or remove 1000-5000 rows, it can be every day). It changes the dataset.
2. Cost changes. It is a constant process. There is a complex algorithm, which calculate price. Some margins or add costs adds constantly and they influence to the set of rows. It changes the order of the search result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-memory solution may be feasible. Since you need to store 12 values x 200M records, you'll need about 20GB of RAM net (assuming 8 bytes per value). You'll need to optimize (stoing 1/2/4 bytes values where possible and disable memory alignments). Practically, you'll probably need a 64GB or stronger machine.

One think you can't afford is using data structures that requires tons of small memory allocations. Even if you'll store the data in a single huge buffer, you'll probably need many small allocations for tree-structure indexes.

There is another reason why trees are not so good for your problem: Since the user may select a set of values for each filter, you'll need to traverse the tree in search for any combination. This can be a huge number of tree traversals.

How about a simpler solution? Select the 2 filters that divide the data-set to the maximal number of groups (this would probably be the filters with the ~5000 values). Use a 2D array. In each cell, if it is not empty, store an array of struct of all remaining 10 values (9 filters + cost). You can sort these arrays by the 3rd most dominant filter.

Upon a user query, determine the relevant cells in the 2D array and check your input against each of the values in the relevant cell (which is sorted by he 3rd most dominant filter). For most cells, you'll have much less than 1000 values to check against.

Depending on your data distribution, you can save some memory by using a sparse matrix instead of a 2D array. Some .NET sparse matrix implementations are available online.

Comment: Thank you! 64-100 GB is a reasonable for us. I'll try 2D array and sparse matrix and post there the result (performance tests and so on)

Answer (score 4):

[TrollModeOn] I had a problem.... tried to solve it with no-sql solution, now i have 2 problems [/TrollModeOff].

As it seems to me, no-sql solution isn't good for handling so much filter's stuff. I'd start from sql-based solution. E.g. if we have ms sql server we can use user defined table types for filters, some kind of:

```
CREATE TYPE [FilterTable] AS TABLE(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL   --or any datatype needed
)
```

After that you can pass table type as a parameter to filtering stored procedure (or do it with sql query), like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SomeFilterProcedureName]
    @Filter1 FilterTable READONLY,
    @Filter2 FilterTable READONLY
    ....
```

And your query would be kind of:

```
SELECT
    field1,
    field2,
    field3
FROM MyTable t
WHERE
    (@Filter1 IS NULL OR t.field1 IN (SELECT id FROM @Filter1))
    AND (@Filter2 IS NULL OR t.field2 IN (SELECT id FROM @Filter2))
    ....
ORDER BY
    whatever
```

So basically you check if your parameters contains some values, if yes - you filter out column values according to filter-parameter data.

RDBMS do exellent work storing, finding, filtering and sorting huge amounts of data, but you'l need to tune it right way to make it work faster, e.g. you will need to set up your indexes correct. Also you can cache data for some period, but make sure you build cache key correct depending on varying parameters.

If your db server isn't good enough to handle 200 queries per second you might want to make a cluster or keep several db servers with same data up and use some kind of db balancer.

**upd: it's too big to place it in comments**

`It the worst case he can select "All" for every 11 filter and we have to sort 192 million records to find 20-100 with the lowest cost`

All filter, lowest cost? Isn't it same as:
`Select top(20) * from someTableName order by cost`.

1. `Db Locks`. Work better on your indexes and queries
2. `Sorting`. Ok, you got 100million records that fit filters. How are you going to sort em? QSort, MergeSort, BubbleSort? Or maybe stackoverflowSort? Do you know which algorythm you have to choose? But first - DBMS knows, and it choses best algorythm for case, cause it has statistics, and second - of course data is stored preordered in indexes. So every 100m record sort operation will kill no-sql solution but will work perfect on rdbms
3. `High load`. Isn't it what we're talking about? In your case it's not real highload there. There are companies that have 100-150 million monthly active users with hella big databases, thousand's of queries per second, and yes, they use rdbms. Dozens of servers, sharding, balancing, and it works perfect.

Comment: +1; I don't see any reason not to go with a relational database here, the project requirements in terms of database size and workload are fairly modest. The only gotcha I can think of is finding a good order for the filters to execute in, but you can probably just rely on the database's query optimizer to take care of this

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot db engine will handle filter order best way based on index selectivity statistic, so you don't have to take care about it

Comment: No, unfortunatelly, it is not a solution for us. In general, we develop a new seach module to replace similar solution. The problem is following:
0. "finding a good order for the filters to execute in" - unfortunatelly, the user can make very wide value's set for every filter, it is important requirement for search. It the worst case he can select "All" for every 11 filter and we have to sort 192 million records to find 20-100 with the lowest cost.

Comment: 1. DB locks. The dataset for search changes often. Some records are added or removed, the Cost field must be recalculated very often for a big set of records. Such big recalculation kills our search engine often.
2. Sorting. We can't make index with big FillFactor for Cost field. Cost changes very often, so RDBMS will rebuild it constantly. But our seach results must be sorted by ascending cost.

Comment: 3. Big load for DB. We made a several DB with replication for search, but it will be nice to avoid this solution. The replication is a complex process, so a lot of clients often have some trouble with it and we have to waste a lot of time to fix their replication. We need more simple solution.

Comment: @SirHally See updates in my answer. It's too big to post it as comment

Answer (score 2):

I think `HBase` we suit your requirement, and for .net compatibility, `hadoop` `.net` sdk is available from `Horton` : [LINK](http://hortonworks.com/blog/hadoop-sdk-and-tutorials-for-microsoft-net-developers/) for more information

Comment: Yes, I've read about Horton. I have one doubt about Hadoop - the reduce stage. Every cluster node returns a set of records, which 
match the filters values, and one node must quickly sort them by cost (ascending). It can make some troubles?

Comment: No output of reduce will not be sorted, But can be done, Because `hadoop` sorts output of mapper So you can create another job nad chain that. You can get more idea by a `wordcount` example given in `hadoop`.

Comment: Thank you for WordCount example, it is plain and good for understanding Hadoop.
"you can create another job nad chain that." - and this job will sort the result of the first job. Is the Map-Reduce good for parallel sort? How it can be organised?

Answer (score 2):

## **This is exactly the scenario SQL is designed for**

SQL Server on a modern system (e.g. Quad Core CPU with 8 GB RAM) can easily handle all the filters, or no filters at all, in the time span you require, provided you create an INDEX on every field you're filtering on.

You could use Sergio's stored procedure to implement the filters; but it's prob. just as easy to just generate the correct SQL statement directly in C# (or VB.NET).

## Profile, profile, profile

Before looking for Map-Reduce or other (b)leading edge technology, try SQL.  Creating the table and indexes can be done in about 15 minutes, and you can time the query.  If it's close to your requirements, then you can begin writing code to generate the correct SQL SELECT based on the filter.  If the SQL query is slower than your requirements, you can decide if you want to optimize it, or look elsewhere.  **But until you've profiled, there's absolutely no reason to try anything else.**

Answer (score 2):

There is a library that you could use. This is Solr. Solr is frequently used when developing application using Java. But you can call Solr from .net too. [Here](http://solrsharp.codeplex.com/)
is one solution and [here](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) is another. It is designed for Big Data. In memory solution can cause problems, especially if we are talking about production.